# I accidentally deleted my git files (in atom, my text editor) hours and hours ago

Tags: git, github, github-pages

My directory was linked to my gh-pages and working fine for weeks.  I deleted a file called .gitfile or something and I thought it was meaningless and clearly it was not.  Now I can't push any changes to my profile page.  I would like to go to my old website murphypicard.github.io and continue to push changes to that one.

The name of my directory is portfoliopage and the url of my gh-pages is murphypicard.github.io

Here are the commands I've tried so far:

```
~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote add origin https://murphypicard.github.io/

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote -v
origin  //murphypicard.github.io/ (fetch)
origin  //murphypicard.github.io/ (push)

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote get-url 
origin //murphypicard.github.io/

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git push -u origin master
fatal: repository //murphypicard.github.io/' not found

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote add origin https://murphypicard.github.io/
fatal: remote origin already exists.

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote add origin git@github.com:MurphyPicard/arayaghsizian.github.io.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git push origin master
fatal: repository //murphypicard.github.io/' not found

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git push gh-pages master
fatal: 'gh-pages' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have also tried set-url with no luck.

Is there a way to push my commits to my old gh-pages?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `.git/config` file and add the correct remote url there.

Something like below:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git@github.com:MurphyPicard/arayaghsizian.github.io.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MurphyPicard/arayaghsizian.github.io.git
```

but, as you can see, the [remote repository](https://github.com/MurphyPicard/arayaghsizian.github.io) is empty.

**Update:**

It's not clear what remote repository you want to use. Please go to your [GitHub page](https://github.com/MurphyPicard), browse the repositories and choose the one you want to link to your local repo.

From your comment to this question it seems that repo is https://github.com/MurphyPicard/murphypicard.github.io. Please open the page of this repo in a browser, push the green button named "Clone or download" (on the right side of the page) and it will show you the URL to use in the `git remote` command.

For `murphypicard.github.io`, the URL is `git@github.com:MurphyPicard/murphypicard.github.io.git`.

Accordingly, your command should be like:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MurphyPicard/murphypicard.github.io.git
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to continue pushing to this:  https://murphypicard.github.io/
I tried:  git remote set-url origin https://murphypicard.github.io/ with no luck

Comment: Stuff I tried: ```~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MurphyPicard.github.io.git

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git push origin master

ERROR: Repository not found.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

~/wdi/portfoliopage (master)$ git push gh-pages master
fatal: 'gh-pages' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```